# How do I make this embedded video 100% wide?

Tags: html, css, iframe, bootstrap-4

I have the code below with one row and two columns. In the first column I would like to display an embedded video from Vimeo. What I want is that the video would fill out its column without having any paddings. The two columns should have no space between them either.

```css
.video iframe {
    width: 100%;
}
.lesson-pager {
    background-color: #00000081;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
                <div class="row video-row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="video">
                            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/42582007" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 lesson-pager">
                        <div class="lesson-title">
                            <h4>Lesson title</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Try removing the `container` class

Comment: Replace iframe attributes `width="640" height="360"` with `width="100%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap-4, you may use the [embed utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/embed/) to make it 100% wide.

```css
.video iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

.lesson-pager {
  background-color: #00000081;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row video-row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="video embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/42582007" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 lesson-pager">
      <div class="lesson-title">
        <h4>Lesson title</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css trick to make it covering full area

```css
.lesson-pager {
    background-color: #00000081;
}
.video{
  position: relative;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.video iframe{
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row video-row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="video">
              <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/42582007" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 lesson-pager">
          <div class="lesson-title">
              <h4>Lesson title</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```